# Merge remaining views with animation after deleting one of the view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have Linear Layout with 4 views. I swipe and delete the View at 2nd position. Now i want the view at 3rd position to merge with the view at 1st position with animation. here is sample code: 
LinearLayout temp = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
temp.removeViewAt(2);

By doing this as soon as the view is removed, the remaining views join each other without animation. i want it to join them with animation.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the android:animateLayoutChanges attribute to true.

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html